# Hash function that is efficient on GPU and poorly suited to ASIC

Tags: hash, algorithm-design, proof-of-work

I have such requirements to the hash function in my project:

- operating on 32-bit data,
- not mathematically breakable (built on existing hashes known to be secure),
- free of branching,
- as much as possible, free of repetitive rounds and rotations,
- long enough to require a huge number of gates on the ASIC.

The idea is to make efficient hash focused on GPU units, and not prospective for ASICs implementation.

(Skein-256 almost seems to fit these requirements?)

Comment: free of repetitive rounds? have fun with that requirement.... Look into Fugue, it has minimal rotation

Comment: right, 'free' is not fortunate word here,
let say: less than usuall,

Comment: The idea is to make efficient hash focused on GPU units, and not prospective for ASICs implementation.

Comment: I like Blake since it is slow on ASIC compared to CPU, and the rotations are mostly on a byte boundary. It can also be modified to use a massive amount of round constants, unique to each round. I would be interested in seeing how changing XOR to + in the compression function effects security, as it would slow ASIC down even more.

Comment: If my memory suits me right, Skein uses at least 80 rounds of Threefish. That's not "less than usual", let alone free of rounds.